# Asciidoc add link to another html file only in toc

Tags: html, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a base asciidoc file where I want to reference other html files. In my current solution, I render them via include all on one page and add a reference to the toc.
This messes up in a very long scrollable page.
That is generally fine but I would prefer the following:

For each addtional html I want to add e reference to the toc only. When klicking this ref, I want to just render the specific html.

Is there a way to do this with the template toc or do I have to use a custom solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for (I think) is one HTML page per Asciidoc markup file, with a common TOC/navigation between them. Normally, this capability is called "chunking", at least the way that DocBook does it.

Unfortunately, `asciidoctor` doesn't have a chunking capability. If you have multiple Asciidoc files, they can be converted to HTML easily, but assembling a common TOC is extra work. Also, cross-reference links between Asciidoc pages is not handled.

You might be interested to learn about Antora (https://antora.org/). It produces a static HTML site from one or more Git repos containing Asciidoc markup files, and each Asciidoc page becomes an HTML page, and there is a common TOC plus cross-reference links. It is, quite likely, a good solution for your current situation.

Comment: Hi, yes that's what I'm searching for. I'll have a look at antora but for me it is not possible to reference my repos from my server because they are hosted in an internal network. As an alternative I thought about writing a custom html page and include the other html pages there.

Comment: As long as the machine that produces HTML can access the repos via HTTP/HTTPS, Antora could work for you. Once the HTML is generated, you can host that however/wherever suits your needs and those of your readers.